# Strangely I cannot get this element by ID even in has an ID

Tags: javascript, html

It seem that I am not able to get the element from a page by using javascript. What am I missing? I did try to fix this for an hour but so far no progress. I preffer javascript over jquery.

```js
<script>
    function dofunc() {
        var content = document.getElementById("textarea").value.trim();
        alert("111");
        alert(content);
        }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="textarea" contenteditable="">I like apples</div>

<input id="sasasa" type="button" value="MORE"onclick="dofunc();" />
```

Comment: you're missing a `}`, so the entire script block is killed due to syntax error

Comment: Does the script to run after the document is fully loaded? Or are you just executing that javascript wherever you happen to write it in your page?

Comment: you have to use `innerHTML` or `textcontent` of that `contenteditable` div

Comment: It works I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `}`. In addition, in your snippet, you don't need to use `<script>` and `</script>` because it is already implied when you write in the javascript box.

Also, you can use `.innerHTML` to get the value in the div and then do what you would like with it.

```js
function dofunc() {
        var content = document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML;
        alert("111");
        alert(content);
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea">I like apples</div>

<input id="sasasa" type="button" value="MORE" onclick="dofunc()" />
```

Comment: `.id` will just return `textarea`, not what the user has typed into it.

Comment: Oh apologies, I thought he was trying to get the id value. I'll adjust it.

Comment: Why would he try to get the ID value when he's looking it up by ID?

Comment: @Barmar because I had a brain fart lol. It happens. I fixed it. Used `.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks this works. Do not know much about javascript so i thought the only way to go is use value atribute :)